# Oracle Apex lock out of my App - Cannot access my own app

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I just imported my app into a different workspace (a developer one) and am having issues while trying to open it up. I get the following error:

Insufficient privileges, user is not a Contributor

Access denied by Application security check
Technical Info (only visible for developers)

```
is_internal_error: true
apex_error_code: APEX.AUTHORIZATION.ACCESS_DENIED
component.type: APEX_APPLICATION_AUTHORIZATION
component.id: 7520010788215408503
component.name: End User Role
error_backtrace:

----- PL/SQL Call Stack -----
  object      line  object
  handle    number  name
0x6e2ee250       960  package body APEX_210100.WWV_FLOW_ERROR.INTERNAL_GET_ERROR
0x6e2ee250      1028  package body APEX_210100.WWV_FLOW_ERROR.INTERNAL_ADD_ERROR
0x6e2ee250      1420  package body APEX_210100.WWV_FLOW_ERROR.RAISE_INTERNAL_ERROR
0xab143348       831  package body APEX_210100.WWV_FLOW_AUTHORIZATION.IS_AUTHORIZED
0x6137ca48      2919  package body APEX_210100.WWV_FLOW.SHOW
0x6137ca48      5323  package body APEX_210100.WWV_FLOW.RESOLVE_FRIENDLY_URL
0xb05740f0         4  anonymous block
```

I tried to add myself as an admin using the following procedure:

```
begin
    APEX_ACL.ADD_USER_ROLE (
        p_application_id => 255,
        p_user_name      => 'SCOTT',
        p_role_static_id => 'ADMINISTRATOR' );
end;
```

And I actually see myself on the apex_appl_acl_user_roles table but still get the same result when trying to open up my app.
Authorization Scheme (shared components -> security) is set to 'End User' (which is basically two levels down on the hierarchy. Admin being the top one).
Does anyone know how to fix this?

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Roles are exported along with the app, users are not. Try giving yourself all roles via Shared Components > Application Access Control. Or use sql commands to backup the other apps' roles and restore them in this workspace. Here is a blog explaining how you can do that: https://seanstuber.com/2019/06/06/extracting-apex-access-control-users/

Comment: Thank you! It was pretty weird....no matter what my role was...it wouldn't let me go in.
The solution was to change the access control to something else and then select the former one again, pretty interesting.
Thanks!